# How to handle outlook custom task pane visibility while inspector menu was open

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created Outlook VSTO Add-in. In Outlook Add-in, I have added custom task pane while the user tries to compose a new mail. Custom task pane was not collapsible. it must be open if my add-in was activated.

I have implemented custom task pane visibility change event. In that event, if the user tried to close custom task pane then I will popup information message. Like, "You are not able to close custom task pane. It will reopen again."

This message appeared while the user clicks on the cross button(Marked with red color in the image) of the custom task pane. 
Like, 
[image]
Up to now it working fine for me. But when the user tries to open the outlook file menu, at that time also custom task pane visible change event was fired.
My informative message will popup. 
[image]

How to handle File menu open in visibility change event?

Answer (score 0):

The Backstage UI provides the following callbacks:

### onShow

```
VBA: Sub OnShow(contextObject As Object)
C#: void OnShow(object contextObject)
Visual Basic: Sub OnShow(contextObject As Object)
C++: HRESULT OnShow([in] Object *pContextObject)
```

### onHide

```
VBA: Sub OnHide(contextObject As Object)
C#: void OnHide(object contextObject)
Visual Basic: Sub OnHide(contextObject As Object)
C++: HRESULT OnHide([in] Object *pContextObject)
```

So, you can skip any processing in the custom task pane when it is overlapped by the backstage UI. The `onShow` callback signals about opening and `onHide` signals about closing the backstage UI.

Read more about the Backstage UI in the [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)#descriptions-attributes-and-child-information-for-the-backstage-view-controls) article.